# Installing pyglfw on OS X

Tags: python, pip, glfw

I want to install glow for python so i runned

```
    pip3 install glfw
```

but when i'm trying to import glfw in code i get error like this

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/glfw.py", line 149, in <module>
    raise ImportError("Failed to load GLFW3 shared library.")
    ImportError: Failed to load GLFW3 shared library.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try downloading the *.tar.gz file and installing that?
It helped me sometimes.

Comment: Where should I install it?

Comment: http://www.glfw.org/download.html

Answer (score 3):

You need to install glfw3 on your system. 
If you use brew `brew install glfw3`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on Ubuntu 18.04. Installation of `libglfw3` and `libglfw3-dev` solved it.

```
apt-get install libglfw3
apt-get install libglfw3-dev
```

I tried to install glfw3 from source first and then install it with brew(as @PanchaGil mentioned above) but it didn't work out for some reason.

Comment: still getting the same error after installing via 'apt' :(

Answer (score 0):

I have hade the same problem.
Just install MS VS C++ and reboot )))