# Import Errror for python pg module

Tags: python, module, pygresql

I am having trouble using the pg module in my code. I've installed it using pip. But when I go to run it I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Contract_gen.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pg
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pg\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .core import (
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pg\core.py", line 6, in <module> 
    from . import glfw
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pg\glfw.py", line 140, in <module>
    raise ImportError("Failed to load GLFW3 shared library.")
ImportError: Failed to load GLFW3 shared library.
```

Comment: Did you try Googling your error message? http://stackoverflow.com/q/35645928/3001761

Comment: I sure did but I did not find that thread! Used pip to install glfw, and I get no change.

Comment: Did you read the answer to that linked question?

Comment: It's not a Python package, that's why.

Comment: If it is not a Python package what is it and where can I find it, brew is the package manager for mac os, correct? I am using Windows atm or Linux at home.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like to require the `GLFW3` library. Download & install it and the error should be gone. If you use macOS you can get it via `brew`.

Comment: I use windows or Linux. Pip does not find GLFW3. I cant seem to find a package index for it either. Where can I find it?

Comment: You can get it from here: http://www.glfw.org/

Please mark the question as answered if it is.

Comment: confirming answer, I was able to get py glfw working after installing glfw through homebrew

Answer (score 0):

Your version of OpenGL might be too old compared to the pg requirement which is 
3.1.0 as specified in
https://github.com/fogleman/pg/blob/master/requirements.txt

You can re install python-openGL with pip:

```
$ pip install PyOpenGL PyOpenGL_accelerate
```

This removes this problem but creates other errors for me.

note, besides, that this problem seems to be mentioned in
https://github.com/fogleman/pg/issues

Answer (score 0):

**How to solve for windows:**

1. Download Windows pre-compiled binaries
   from https://www.glfw.org/download.html
2. copy (and replace) the file lib-mingw-w64\glfw3.dll to ...\Python27\Lib\site-packages\glfw\glfw3.dll
3. Done

For me, glfw was working fine until one morning when it suddenly wasn't. This solution worked for me. I don't know if this is the correct way to solve it but it worked for me.