# Installation of GLFW

Tags: python, python-3.x, glfw

I'm using Python 3.5 on Ubuntu 16.  On my system, pip3 seems to think that GLFW is installed (requirements are satisfied), but upon calling up the python3 interpreter, I get an import error:

```
>>> import glfw
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/glfw.py", line 194, in <module>
    raise ImportError("Failed to load GLFW3 shared library.")
ImportError: Failed to load GLFW3 shared library.
```

Any suggestions as to how to debug this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to install GLFW onto your system before you can successfully use the python package. [Previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35645928/installing-pyglfw-on-os-x).

Comment: That post doesn't really address the underlying problem, they just suggest using a different package manager.  GLFW seems to be installed (at least according to pip), why would using brew make a difference?

Comment: There should be two things that you should install to make this work.  1. Install the GLFW OpenGL library from [here](http://www.glfw.org/). 2. Install the python bindings that interact with the installed library.  The pip package you install is just a binding that interacts with the GLFW OpenGL Library.